# How to find the wattage of a power relay?

Tags: relay, power-electronics

I have a relay here -

[image: Relay]

Is there a way of knowing the wattage of this relay? It could be anything from 0.36W to 0.54W but since I dont have the datasheet I can't tell exactly how much it is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about applying 5 V to the relay's coil and measuring the current it takes. Multiply current and voltage and you will know the power the relay takes.

Comment: \$5\:\text{V}\$ relays like these are almost always designed to a standard of about \$70\:\Omega\$. There are good reasons related to inductance and the L/R time constant that go beyond "just a standard" for this, so you can almost bet on it. (Nothing is ever sure, though.) If I'm right (and I'm betting I am) then it is \$360\:\text{mW}\$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I used this method and got 0.357 so 0.36W it is.

Comment: The fastest way for me is to read the datasheet. https://www.google.ca/search?q=jqc3f+datasheet&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=NGivWsX8C62Q8Qf6kJmYCQ

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 you beat me to it by seconds while I was uploading the picture in my answer! :D

Comment: These relays are typically 200mW (sensitive), 360mW (normal) or 450mW (high current). Goodness knows what you'll get the next time you order them if they don't build the sensitivity into the part number.

Comment: Wondering WHY you need to know the wattage. Makes me suspect the real answer here may include the contact resistance power dissipation which from the really bad spec sheet I assume to be 0.1R

Answer (score 3):

The marking on the relay tells you it takes 5v.

Apply 5v, and measure the current. Multiply the current by 5v, to get watts.

The temperature coefficient of resistance for copper is about +10% per 25 degrees C rise. If the relay is going to be used in a hot environment, you will find that it takes less power when hot. It will also be taking slightly less power after being on for several minutes, due to self heating. Expect that drift, don't let it confuse you into thinking something mysterious is happening. In fact, I often measure winding resistance to estimate how hot copper coils have become in use.

Answer (score 1):

Measure the coil resistance (R) and do the numbers ( Power=25/R ).

Answer (score 0):

[Look up the datasheet on google](https://www.google.no/search?biw=950&bih=1049&ei=I2ivWr-cNLKJmwWV9JKoBQ&q=he%20jqc3fc%20relay%20datasheet&oq=HE%20JQC3FC&gs_l=psy-ab.1.4.0i71k1l8.0.0.0.6705.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.965UmEGRyN8) and you will find [what you need](https://voron.ua/files/pdf/relay/JQC-3F(T73).pdf)

[image]

Comment: Yeah. But that doesn't say exactly. I saw the same thing and decided not to say anything at all about that sheet.

Comment: Well, I felt that manufacturer specification also deserves a spot when the two other answers go the experimental route. If I had doubts about the spec from the datasheet, I would consider the worst case anyway.

Comment: The op had already spec'd a range. It was clear to me the op was looking for a more precise figure. Turns out there are good reasons that all such relays are made quite similarly and therefore the value is predictable, regardless of the manufacturer. I'm not complaining so much as pointing out that it didn't really do much to refine the OP's original question which already included a range. Take it for what it's worth. It's not a negative to find a link. It's just that the link doesn't always help that much.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree, I just interpreted the information differently. The range from OP is just something that is stated without a source, and the absence of a datasheet is listed as a reason for not knowing the exact figure. IMO, the datasheet does not refer a range, but two discrete numbers. I interpreted it as matter of comparing the guesstimate and the specifications, and seeing what was more correct. (Also, the datasheet _might_ be interpreted such that the highest power spec correspond to the highest drive voltage)

Comment: I think the subject is kind of interesting. They have a fixed volume for these units and need a specific magnetic force (ampere-turns.) The volume limit means that coil resistance R=V/I is proportional to the number of turns squared, N^2. But N*I must be constant. So N is proportional to V. So to double the coil voltage, the current is halved, N is doubled, and the resistance is four times more. So R is some constant K times V^2. Inductance L goes by N^2 but R also goes by N^2, too, so L/R is also a constant 'time constant.' Pretty much everything is determined by the volume and materials.

Comment: data sheet says it's 0.45W for the dual throw (form C) version of the relay, and 0.36 for the single throw (form A) version

Comment: That data sheet does not explain the markings on that relay. (wrong data sheet)

Comment: Love the contact resistance in that spec sheet \$<=100M\Omega\$ I guess they mean \$m\Omega\$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question why you need to know the wattage of the relay, so I am going to assume you are trying to figure out how much heat you will need to get rid of.

From [an equivalent part spec-sheet](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/114955/ETC1/JQC-3F.html) you can see the \$5V\$ coil has about \$70\Omega\$ coil resistance giving you that \$0.35W\$ coil power number.

However, the contact resistance maximum on that part is \$50m\Omega\$. If you are running it at the rated \$10A\$ that's a whopping maximum of \$5W\$. If you use the data sheet mentioned in [MrGerber's Answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/363407/139766), that one has a maximum of \$10W\$ at the contacts.

As such, the power dissipated by the contacts can swamp the coil power and is important to consider when performing heat analysis of your design.